# Adding a Custom Font (Lexia)

Tags: ios, xcode4.6, uifont, info.plist, custom-font

i am trying to add Font Lexia into my project but its not working. what i did was;

i downloaded .ttf files from here: http://www.dafont.com/lexia.font

dragged two `LEXIA___.ttf` and `LEXIB___.tff` files into the project and added them to the target as well (i even tried copying them into Bundle Resources)

then i added them in plist file but of no use. (i tried using different names but didnt work)

i tried to get names in the code but its not appearing there

```
NSArray *arrFonts = [UIFont familyNames];
NSLog(@"name = %@",arrFonts);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ttf files need to be added to the Resources section of your project. Then the names you put in the Info.plist file (your Marsden-Info.plist) needs to match the filenames of the ttf files.

You entered `Lexia-Regular.ttf` and `Lexia-Bold.ttf` but the files appear to be named `LEXIA___.ttf` and `LEXIB___.ttf`. The names must match exactly, including case.